# monkeyrunner - get currently active application?

Tags: java, android, monkeyrunner

I'm using the android monkeyrunner to automatically run my application.

```
monkeyDevice.executeShellCommand("am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n " 
            + name + " -e test_id " + test_id, new NullOutputReceiver());
```

Is it possible to get the name of the active application that is on the emulator screen using monkeyrunner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current focused window using:

```
hv = monkeyDevice.getHierarchyViewer()
windowName = hv.getFocusedWindowName()
```

Comment: For some reason I don't have the `getHierarchyViewer` method available for my `monkeyDevice`? Any documentation for this?

Comment: I assume: monkeyDevice = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection() and latest monkeyrunner (rev 16)